# Difference between DV01 and IR DV01

Tags: fixed-income, bond, duration

What is the difference between DV01 and IR DV01? As far as I can see DV01 is at point on the yield curve and IR DV01 represents a parallel shift of the entire yield curve? My understanding is still shaky so some clarification would be greatful as I cannot find this on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DV01 is the dollar variation in a bond's value per unit change in the yield.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_duration

IR DV01 is the dollar value change for a 1bp upward parallel shift in interest rates.
http://dataforthoughts.blogspot.it/2009/09/economics-of-negative-bond-cds-basis.html